# Scrypt cipher - known vulnerabilities and cryptanalysis?

Tags: cryptanalysis, collision-resistance, key-derivation, proof-of-work, scrypt

there is a Scrypt cipher which is used for exmaple by some cryptos like LItecoin for their mining algorithm.

I never heared of scrypt. I know eg SHA256 which is well analyzed and considered as secure until now.

1) ANy known crypatanalysis for scrypt / vulnerabilities?

2) is scrypt considered in the community as a secure (comparable to sha256) cipher?

3) How collision-resistant is it?

4) Is it easily breakable by quantum computing attacks?

Thanks

Comment: This is the same as your migrated question. Please delete one.

Comment: I have closed this one, so that the migration from security.se doesn't get bounced back and we have only one copy to keep track of.